# Angular2 Async validator

Tags: angular2-forms

Sorry for my bad english.

I'm trying to use a custom async validation in my angular application like this

```
 asyncValidator(control:FormControl):Promise<any>{
    const promise = new Promise<any>(
      (resolve, reject) =>{
        setTimeout(() => {
          console.log("it works");
          resolve(null);
        },5000);
      }
    );
    return promise;
  }
```

I declared my reactive form like this:

```
this.customForm = this.formbuilder.group({
      'userData': this.formbuilder.group({
        'name': ['',this.asyncValidator],
        'email': [''],
      }),
      'pass': [''],
      'gender': ['male'],
      'hobbies': this.formbuilder.array([
        ['Reading']
      ])
    })
```

Even though, the asyncValidator always resolve(null), the name input still has ng-invalid class.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly placed your async validator.

It should be:

```
'name': ['', null, this.asyncValidator],
         (1)  (2)          (3)
```

where:

(1) - control value

(2) - sync validator

(3) - async validator

**[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukckkx?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**